# Add image just into a bottom or top in QT App with StyleSheet(QStyle)

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

How can i add image just into the bottom or up of the Form in QT with Stylesheet.
for example, i want to add image that you can see it at image below and then set padding of the form:

link of image:
http://0000.2.img98.net/out.php/i11716_bg-header2.jpg

Please explain it with CSS Commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with qss (css). But in order to enable the stylesheets in your custom QWidget you will have to handle the Paint event.

mywidget.cpp

```
void QMyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```

Add your css (qss) in the resources and add alias name, which will be used as filename for loading.

You can add this method in the main window, to load stylesheet.

mymainwindow.cpp

```
void QMyMainWindow::loadStyleSheet(QString path)
{
    QFile data(path);
    QString style;
    if(!data.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
        return false;

    QTextStream styleIn(&data);
    style = styleIn.readAll();
    data.close();

    qApp->setStyleSheet(qApp->styleSheet().append(style));
}
```

Then call this function with the resource alias name of QSS (CSS) file. You can do this in the constructor or in resize event (for mobile development) to track and load different styles for different resolutions.

Comment: I've been added this image to my resource, but i like to know how can i do that with CSS.

Comment: Yes, add the stylesheet, too. Call them by resource alias, and in css: `background-image: url('path_in_resource_to_img_alias');`